# Kinematics of a Particle Derivatives in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

So I am trying to differentiate in Mathematica some simple equations of motion but I am not getting full solutions out of Mathematica.

I have a particle with position vector defined as:

r = 100*Sec(theta)

the velocity or first derivative is correct in mathematica except it is missing the additonal theta dot term...what am I doing wrong?

r' or v = 100*Sec(theta)*Tan(theta)*thetadot

but Mathematica only shows:

v = 100*Sec(theta)*Tan(theta)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Functions are defined using square brackets, not parentheses. Hence Tan[ ] and Sec[ ], instead of Tan( ) and Sec( ).

Comment: You apparently want `Dt[r]` which evaluates to `100 Dt[theta] Sec[theta] Tan[theta]`

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: theta is interpreted as variable, not as a function. For a function you need to specify an argument. E.g.: theta[t]

Comment: Thank you all, I was missing the theta wrt to time i.e. Theta[t]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function arguments have square brackets  f[t], round brackets are used only to encapsilate expressions as argument of the arithmetical functions; or in a series of compound statements of semicolon separated lists of expressions, where the semicolon supresses the intermediate results.

```
(r[t_]  = 100 Sech[theta[t]]; 
 vr[t_] = D[r[t], t];
 ar[t_] = D[vr[t], t]),  

  Out=-100*Sech[theta[t]]^3* theta'[t]^2 + 
       100*Sech[theta[t]]*Tanh[theta[t]]^2* theta'[t]^2 -
       100*Sech[theta[t]]*Tanh[theta[t]]*theta''[t]
```

Curly brackets of comma separated list denote List objects, that serve e.g. as vectors, List of Lists as matrices or just as list of anything to be put together and to be called by a name={1,2,3}

```
FullSimplify[Replace[{ r[ s], vr[s], ar[s]}  {f_[s]->f}  ] // TableForm

Out={100 Sech[theta],
     -100 Sech[theta] Tanh[theta] theta',
      50 Sech[theta]^3((-3+Cosh[2 theta]) (theta')^2-Sinh[2 theta] theta'')
```

Comment: Thank you, it was Sec[theta[t]] I was missing...thank you for the help!